# Are there any fonts that write q with a v-hook?

Tags: fonts

I want a sans-serif font that renders q with a v-hook, as shown here:

[image]

I do NOT want a curved u-hook.

Answer (score 0):

For a not-so-minimalistic font (but san-serif), check out "Open Dyslexic" here: https://www.fontspace.com/unicode/char/024B-latin-small-letter-q-with-hook-tail

NOTE: I found the page via google image search on the provided glyph.